# How to put an image after some text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wish to put an image after a few items in a Wordpress site. I don't want to place an image after all similar items, only specific ones.

Thankfully each specific item generates it's own css class.

I thought using `:after` would be the answer but i'm failing somewhere.

```
<div id="menu_4212" class="menu_content_classic">
<h5 class="menu_post">
    <span class="menu_title">Onion Soup</span>
    <span class="menu_dots"></span><span class="menu_price">€4.50</span>
</h5>
```

I want to place the image after "Onion Soup"

So I tried this approach to target specifically `#menu_4212`:

```
#menu_4212.menu_post.menu_title::after {
  content: url('..images/gluten_free.png')
}
```

I think i may have got the div hierarchy wrong, any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 7):

Technically you cannot insert an image tag in between the two `<span>` tags via CSS, let's say:

```
.menu_title::after {
  content: "NEW";
}
```

That will insert it to `<span class="menu_title">Onion SoupNEW</span>`

It will be the same if you're trying to insert an image:

```
.menu_title::after {
  content: url('..images/gluten_free.png');
}
```

The problem is your selectors `#menu_4212.menu_post.menu_title::after`, it targets everything is on the same element, e.g. `<span id="menu_4212" class="menu_post menu_title">`

With your markup you should do this, mind the gap.

```
#menu_4212. menu_post. menu_title::after {
  content: url('..images/gluten_free.png')
}
```

And be aware, with this method, you won't be able to control the size of the image via CSS. You can however use background images.

```
#menu_4212. menu_post. menu_title::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url('..images/gluten_free.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

In addition, you can also insert the image via `.menu_post::after {...}`, then use flexbox `order` property to reorder them, make the image to show in the middle of the spans visually.

Comment: While some of the other suggestions worked somewhat, they also pushed content out of line .. Your final suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you for your assistance .

Comment: I was about to create a flexbox example, look like you figured it out already :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#menu_4212 .menu_post .menu_title::after {
  content: url('..images/gluten_free.png')
}
```

Your current code assumes the ID & 2 classes are all on the same element. You want to use the "[descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)" syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you can give your `:after` pseudo-element some `display` property and also specify it's dimensions. Then put image on the background. It will give you some flexibility for styling the image.

Something like this (style to your own needs):

```
#menu_4212 .menu_post .menu_title::after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background: url('..images/gluten_free.png') no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I'll be more than happy to hear why my answer is downvoted?

Comment: Because that's not true. you do **not** need a display or dimensions. see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/24fpru8f/1/)

Comment: That's absolutely valid approach and it gives a lot of flexibility over just putting the image there. I will change 'need' to 'can' if that helps.

Comment: Yes it is valid. But valid and required are two different things